# Get location of specific SCCM device collection in Powershell

Tags: powershell, sccm

I am writing a script to export the names of all computer in a device collection to a txt file. My script works as expected but I would like to preserve the folder structure in the exported file structure. For this I need to get the location of the Device Collection.

My Question:
Is there a way to get the location of a SCCM Device Collection in PowerShell?

I've stumbled across a few posts like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/SCCM/comments/63zcew/find_the_location_of_a_collection/) and [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2589a4d0-3e60-44be-945a-469a47333492/list-all-collections-under-a-specific-folder-with-powershell?forum=ConfigMgrCBGeneral) that use WMI and WQL for this, but I wasn't able to get those working in my script and I would like to do everything in PowerShell whenever possible.

```
$collections = (Get-CMDeviceCollection | Select -ExpandProperty "Name")

$totalCollections = $collections.length

"Number of Collections: $totalCollections"

$i = 0
foreach($name in $collections){
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        $i++
        "Writing File $i of $totalCollections"
        $SanitizedName = $name -replace '/','(slash)' -replace '\\','(backslash)' -replace ':','(colon)' -replace '\*','(asterisk)' -replace '\?','(questionmark)' -replace '"','(quote)' -replace '<','(less)' -replace '>','(more)' -replace '\|','(pipe)'
        $file = New-Item -Path "C:\Temp\exporte\$SanitizedName.txt"
        Add-Content -Path $file.FullName -Value (Get-CMCollectionMember -CollectionName $name | Select -ExpandProperty "Name")
    }
}
```

I would like to expand this code so that the txt files are placed in the corresponding subfolder analog to the SCCM file structure. E.g rootFolder/rooms/

I was using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configurationmanager/?view=sccm-ps) module until now but wasn't able to find anything that gives me back the specific location of a collection.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Might want to think about querying SQL directly, if you have a *really* huge SCCM deployment, as something to consider.

Comment: @FoxDeploy I have thought about this too. But I was wondering if there was a way to do it all in "normal PowerShell" since I would like to minimize the complexity of the script. But if nothing turns up I will look into this. thx

Comment: If you want to do everything from PowerShell, I understand that.  Just query SCCM's SQL Database from PowerShell as seen in this guide.  https://github.com/fredbainbridge/mms2019ConfigMgrPowershellDemos/blob/master/demo4-SQL.ps1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a way to do this in plain PowerShell and the SCCM Module. In the end I did it like @FoxDeploy suggested. I made a SQL query select for each collection (performance isn't an issue in my case) on our SCCM database to get the folder path. I then used this to place the export file in the appropriate place.

This is my working example with some confidential lines removed

```
## Parameter ##
$exportLocation = [removed]
$sqlServer = [removed]
$db = [removed]

$query = "SELECT [ObjectPath] FROM [removed].[v_Collections] WHERE CollectionName ="

$SiteCode = [removed] # Site code 
$ProviderMachineName = [removed] # SMS Provider machine name

# Customizations
$initParams = @{}

# Import the ConfigurationManager.psd1 module 
if((Get-Module ConfigurationManager) -eq $null) {
    Import-Module [removed]\..\ConfigurationManager.psd1" @initParams 
}

# Connect to the site's drive if it is not already present
if((Get-PSDrive -Name $SiteCode -PSProvider CMSite -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    New-PSDrive -Name $SiteCode -PSProvider CMSite -Root $ProviderMachineName @initParams
}

Set-Location "$($SiteCode):\" @initParams

# get all collections and save them to an array
$collections = (Get-CMDeviceCollection | Select -ExpandProperty "Name")

# total number of collections
$totalCollections = $collections.length

# output to console
"Number of Collections: $totalCollections"

# empty output directory
Set-Location [removed]
Remove-Item $exportLocation\* -Recurse -Force
Set-Location [removed]

# loop through all collections
$i = 0
foreach($name in $collections){
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        # print progress
        $i++
        "Writing File $i of $totalCollections"
        # remove all characters, that aren't compatible with the windows file naming scheme (/\:*?"<>|)
        $SanitizedName = $name -replace '/','(slash)' -replace '\\','(backslash)' -replace ':','(colon)' -replace '\*','(asterisk)' -replace '\?','(questionmark)' -replace '"','(quote)' -replace '<','(less)' -replace '>','(more)' -replace '\|','(pipe)'
        # get members of collection
        $collectionMembers = (Get-CMCollectionMember -CollectionName $name | Select -ExpandProperty "Name")
        # write to file
        Set-Location [removed]
        $path = (Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sqlServer -Database $db -Query "$query '$collection'").Item("ObjectPath")
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$exportLocation$path"
        $file = New-Item -Path "$exportLocation$path\$SanitizedName.txt"
        Add-Content -Path $file.FullName -Value $collectionMembers
        Set-Location [removed]
    }
}
```

hope this helps someone. Thanks @FoxDeploy